# Wordpress Materialis theme and Radio button issue

Tags: html, radio-button, wordpress-theming

My Wordpress site was active with the theme Materialis (Version: 1.0.167), I use Elementor Plugin to build my pages and adding to that I use some custom code to build Forms using PHP+HTML option of WordPress component. Issue was trying to add Radio button and it is not even getting displayed with radio options instead it shows some lines.

Following is the HTML code that I used to build input field - @type='text' - it was working fine as expected.

```
<div class="col-md-6 form-group">
<label for="reg_city" class="control-label">City <span style="color:blue;"><b>*</b></span></label>
<input  name="reg_city" type="text"  class="form-control" required id="js_reg_city" placeholder="">
</div>
```

Similarly, I was trying to build radio button and it **failed to display**.

```
<div id="GST_Porcess" class="col-sm-4">
<label>
<input type="radio" name="invGST_status" id="invGST_status_yes" onclick="GST_YES()" checked  value="Yes"  > <small><sup><span style="font-size:17px;">Yes</span></sup></small>
</label>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="invGST_status"  id="invGST_status_no" onclick="GST_NO()" value="No" > <small><sup><span style="font-size:17px;">No</span></sup></small>
</label>
</div>
```

Here with enclosed the snapshot of the result for your reference.

[image: Snapshot]

Comment: use the code inspector and make sure the label tag doesn't have any css messing up

Comment: Added custom CSS code - and sounds okay. Thanks for the help